# FluentValidation : set a default value on error

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to set a default value to a field with FluentValidation when the provided value is invalid (ex: if the provided language isn't supported, put an error message and default the language to english). I know it's not a good practice to change a value in a validation but in the case of language, I need it to be properly set for further validations and to display the error messages.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this *within* a fluent validation validator. The validator class should only be concerned with providing validation: this is its single responsibility.

To do what you describe, you could perform the validation and then check for the language related error at which point you could set the default value.

Or perhaps you could default the language value prior to validation - it's difficult to make a recommendation without any code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't find a better way to fix that issue.

Comment: Actually, there might be valid cases when you want to set some values to null. I will give you an example. I have an UI where depending on selections in drop-down lists certain fields become required and others not. The users can flip between these selections and set values and so on. When the data is saved I use FV to validate the form. What's happening is that I want to set those values that don't apply to null - that's how they are stored in the database. In FV I already check all the selections and the field values. I wish there was a way to transform the data during the validation.

Comment: (continued) to avoid duplicating some of the logic in the validator.